How to customize the caption text in Folium colorbar? I want to increase the font size of the colormap caption text
I am trying to use colorbar for an output variable circle plot in Folium
colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['green','red'], index=[min(df['output']), max(df['output'])], vmin=min(df['output']),vmax=max(df['output']), caption='output in units')

folium.Circle(location=[row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']], 
                        radius=800*row["output"],
                        fill=True,
                        # opacity=0.8,
                        # fill_opacity=1,
                        color=colormap(row["output"])).add_to(m)

When  I use this code, the caption text "output in units" is appearing very small. How to increase its font size?

AFAIK, there is no direct way to do it but, you can inject CSS using the font-size property.
By inspecting the html's folium Map (with CTRL+SHIFT+I) on Chrome, the caption's text seems to be at #legend > g > text :

import folium
import pandas as pd
import branca.colormap as cm

df = pd.DataFrame({"output": range(10, 110, 10)})
agg = df["output"].agg(vmin="min", vmax="max")

m = folium.Map([39.5, -98.35], zoom_start=4)

colormap = cm.LinearColormap(
    colors=["green", "red"],
    index=agg.to_list(),
    caption="output in units",
    **agg.to_dict(),
)

CSS = "font-size: 16px;" # add more props if needed

m.get_root().header.add_child(
    folium.Element(f"&ltstyle>#legend > g > text.caption {{{CSS}}}</style>")
)

colormap.add_to(m)


That was helpful. Could you please point out how to change the location of the color bar to move from "topright" to "topleft." I was able to do it directly editing the HTML file, but I prefer to do it in the code itself.

That's not what you ask in the first time. To avoid moving targets, you can open a new question ;)

I just did.  please consider answering it.
